# Sencha Touch 2 Navigation Bar Title

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha touch 2 application that uses a navigation view and has a list of items.  When someone clicks on an item and I dynamically change title of the navigation bar to be the item the person clicked on and also add 3 buttons to the navigation bar.  However when the user clicks on an item and the screen is re-sized to be small the title is not formatted correctly.

Is there an event that happens after a panel is rendered so I can call refreshTitlePosition()?

Comment: why do you have to observe event when a panel is rendered? It should be `itemtap`, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called resize for every container in sencha... 
Hope it helps...